# windows explorer crashes if I hit Bluetooth link to my old phone

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have a link in my windows Explorer to my old Nokia phone
if I move the mouse during a Drag&Drop operation over it, the explorer stop working and i have is restarted...

How I get rid of this symbol?
(see [screenshot](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/6311/unbenanntkdr.png))

using Windows 7 Professional (SP1)
I removed all of the nokia software on my device, still no luck

It also doesn't matter if I enable/disable the Bluetooth device on my notebook.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Explorer would just crash randomly while dragging files, then I realized it happened if I drag over a Bluetooth phone.

Comment: This should help, though: http://lifehacker.com/5745233/keep-the-windows-desktop-from-crashing-by-sandboxing-explorer-windows

Comment: Thanks for the tipp but this is only a workaround, I would like to get rid of the symbol because its not working any more

Comment: yeah, I know. me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid infuriating Bluetooth devices:

[image]

- Delete does nothing
- Shift+Delete does nothing
- They don't show up in Device Manager
- They don't show up in Devices and Printers
- Selecting them and pressing the right mouse button or the context menu button on the keyboard crashes Windows Explorer
- Dragging a file past them crashes Windows Explorer

[image]

[Here is a way to prevent the crashes](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/108821-remove-device-showing-mycomputer.html#post938013):

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID
3. Edit → Find → Search for the name of the devices
4. Delete the key

[image]

You can now select and delete the icons:

[image]

Comment: Hi

thanks for the answer
I deleted the entry from the registry, The icons changed the way you described but I'm not able to delete this icons
After deleting they will be back when refreshing the explorer

Comment: @nobs: Hmm...  it works for me.  Have you killed Explorer or restarted the computer?

Comment: rebooting did the trick, thanks!
I wanted to vote up, but my rep isnt good enough :-(